# Rails extend time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to extend the `time_ago_in_words` helper to include html.

Is this possible?

Essentially I would like to add a date element wrapper to the content and give the date element a title based on the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply override it in application_helper.rb. Then, using super, you can get the return value of the core method and add HTML to it that way.

For example to add bold tags around it:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def time_ago_in_words(time)
    ("<b>" + super + "</b>").html_safe
  end
```